Debug .net 8 browser-wasm hosted in ASP.NET MVC on IIS
I have an old ASP.NET MVC app with .NET Framework 4.8 hosted on IIS and I am trying to add some client side logic in C# with WASM in .net 8. I already have a big logic written in C# and would like to reuse it.
I can easily run said C# code in the browser following stuff like "Run .NET from JavaScript | Microsoft Learn". I have a "XCOPY" command to copy the "_framework" and "main.js" to a directory served by the ASP.NET MVC app.
The problem is that I can't manage to debug it. Starting the ASP.NET app in VS with "IIS Express" opens up the app properly, my C# code is loaded and runs properly in the browser but I can't put any breakpoint.
I have also tried to "attach" to the browser directly, which worked but still no luck with the breakpoints.
I have tried to debug it in the browser directly as a compromise but even that, all the stuff I find says to do "alt+shift+D" in the browser, which doesn't do anything and I can't find any doc about it online.
Anyone has an idea?
